Does the angular signal need to be a signal object or a primitive value inside?
In the previous code, Angular v.14 I have eg. two objects:
objA{name:sring, value: number}, objB{name:sring, value: number}, 

And a list of this objects:
ObjList[objA,objb]

In a template I iterate over this ObjList
<table *ngFor="let obj of ObjList; let i = index "> 
    <input [(ngModel)]='obj .name' 
           (keyup)=' keyup (obj)' > 
    <input [(ngModel)]='obj .value' > 
           (keyup)=' keyup (obj)' 
</table>

Which ends at east into a way binding of the primitive values and in a related key-up function for each individual object.
The properties are mutable and will results changes in between each object properties too.
So must the properties a signal or is it enough, that the object itself will be a signal. I not clearly understand the new change detection as
A) Both, objects and properties will be converted to signal
B) only the object will be converted to the signal
C) only the properties will be converted to signals
To have the correct change detection strategy?

When calling [(ngModel)]="myObj.myProp" you're effectively mutating myObj.
If only myObj is a signal, the mutation wouldn't dirty the signal and the reactive tree would be notified of the change.
You will need to have a signal on myProp for it to be reactive.
The DX around forms with signal isn't optimal today and requires some from work from the Angular team to be improved.
Structures like DeepSignals (like proposed by the NgRx SignalStore) are an alternative to workaround this issue.
